# Missing Maven2 artifacts in fresh Eclipse install

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've just installed a fresh copy of SpringSource Toolsuite 2.7.1 and tried to Import a working project from SVN, when I try to build it I obtain the following errors:

```
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
...
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: Maven Builder: FULL_BUILD requireFullBuild
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.asd:si:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 312, column 12
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 373, column 12
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ line 320, column 12
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] 
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
31/07/11 17:15:04 ART: [WARN]
```

In my pom.xml all dependencies are configured OK, this project works fine in other installations...

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by other installations? Are these other installations on different machines?

Comment: Just a note: if using embedded maven which ships with sts 2.7.1, maven is version 3. Check if your settings.xml is equivalent to that installed in other installations.

Comment: @mkro: you're right, on other machines.

Comment: @guido: good point, i'll take a look at it!

Comment: Where are the errors? I see only warning which are normal when runnning a maven2 pom using maven3.  maven3 requires plugin versions to be explicitly specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you configured your external Maven installation in the m2eclipse plugin. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installation and configure it there.
Also, note that the Maven plugin that comes with Indigo doesn't work as previous versions and some Maven plugins may not be  directly supported.
Furthermore, if you haven't used Maven 3 before and you have plugin version numbers coded in your POM's there may be incompatibilities, as not all plugins that worked with Maven 2 work with Maven 3 as well. All should have updates that do, though. Note that specifying plugin version numbers is a good habit and Maven 3 warns you if you don't. If you haven't done it already try and build your project with Maven 3 from the command line, to get a more precise idea of where the problem lies.